# Add quotations in multiple lines with vim

Tags: vim

I forgot to enclose the keys in the dictionary with single quotes. What's the fastest way to do this with vim?

```
fName: 'Please enter your full name:',
employed: "Are you employed (enter 'y' for yes and 'n' for no)?",
salary: 'Please enter your current salary:',
incRate: 'Please enter your percent pay increase:'
```

Currently, these are my steps.

Go to beginning of 'fName', insert mode, insert ', w command, insert ', down j command, back word b command, repeat above.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `%s/^/'/` and `%s/:/':/` If that is not the full document, use visual mode to select the lines and use the `s` command

Comment: I'd use `%norm I'<C-v><esq>ea'`

Comment: @balki Googling it further, it looks like the caret (^) indicates start of the line. However, my line is indented so that command adds the single quote on the far left of the line, instead of to the left of the first word. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: just for your last question. `^\s*` matches until your first non-whitespace char. you can solve your problem with capturing groups: `:%s/\v(^\s*)(\w*):/\1\'\2\':`

Comment: @VanNguyen If your code is indented you should post it format as it is.

Answer (score 3):

Many people use the [surround.vim](https://vim.sourceforge.io/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697) plugin for that. With it, you can surround the current word with `ysiw'`. (`ys` - surround, `iw` - inner word, `'` - with single quotes). With [repeat.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2136), you can apply this to following lines via `j.`.

Comment: surround.vim was my first idea too, since i use it heavily. But if you use surround i woult suggets `:g/:/norm ^ysiw'` which would save you from manual repeating.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
ciw'<C-r><C-o>'<Esc>
2_.   or j0.
2_.
2_.
```

Reference:

```
:help c
:help iw
:help i_ctrl-r_ctrl-o
:help _
```

Comment: I would use `+`/`<cr>` instead of `2_` to advance to the next line